# Internet Explorer and html div title

Tags: html

I'm using the following HTML code to successfully show the title in FF and Chrome but it doesn't appear in IE - even IE9. I'm I doing something wrong? does this work for others?

```
<div class="emoticonTitleWink" title="Wink ;)"></div>
```

any advise welcome...

FYI the classe

```
div.emoticonTitleWink {
position: absolute;
width: 18px;
height: 18px;
left: 79px;
top: 59px;
}
```

Is there a way to get the small pop (text info) to occur in IE?

thx

Comment: It works for me in IE 8: [http://jsfiddle.net/w9GRs/](http://jsfiddle.net/w9GRs/) Your example shows no text in the div...I presume that in your actual page, it has text?

Comment: Is this online? Do you have an example of it happening?

Comment: Seems to work for me (IE8): http://jsfiddle.net/4HFFe/

Comment: My tests show it works in IE9, IE8 and IE7. It does not work in IE6. [This is the Fiddle I tested with](http://jsfiddle.net/mHeaz/). There should be something else that breaks it for you. Please check the fiddles and elaborate.

Comment: Make sure you are using a standards mode doctype on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Per the above comments, it is working for me in IE 8 too. Strange.

Nonetheless, if all fails, you could resort to IE conditional comments. These comments allow you to assign specific HTML just for Internet Explorer (or even different versions of Internet Explorer).

Here are the details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

In your case, you could perhaps use a javascript/jQuery script in IE instead of using the title attribute if you really must need for this title to work in IE.